# multipe $http calls inside a controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement wego API in angularJS. The problem that I am facing is,To get the hotels list, I need to make three API calls, the result of each giving some information, which needs to be passed onto the next API call. The problem that I am facing is, I am able to make the 1st call successfully, but not proceed further. I tried using console.log and found that after the 2nd API call is made, the execution neither goes to the success callback, nor to the error callback.
Here is my code :-

```
var app = angular.module('tripochill', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log) {

  $scope.city = "";
  $scope.ts_code = #####;
  $scope.key = ##########;

  $("#from").on("change", function() {
    $scope.checkin = $(this).val();
    console.log($scope.checkin);

    chk = $scope.checkin;
    day = chk.substr(0, 2);
    mon = chk.substr(3, 2);
    yr = chk.substr(6);
    $scope.checkin = (yr + "-" + day + "-" + mon);

    console.log($scope.checkin);
  });


  $("#to").on("change", function() {
    $scope.checkout = $(this).val();
    console.log($scope.checkout);

    chk = $scope.checkout;
    day = chk.substr(0, 2);
    mon = chk.substr(3, 2);
    yr = chk.substr(6);
    $scope.checkout = (yr + "-" + day + "-" + mon);

    console.log($scope.checkout);
  });

  console.log($scope.city[0]);

  $scope.cityNames = function() {
    $http.get("http://api.wego.com/hotels/api/locations/search?q=" + $scope.city[0] + "&ts_code=" + $scope.ts_code + "&key=" + $scope.key)
      .then(onSuccessName, onErrorName);
  };
  //Success method
  var onSuccessName = function(response) {
    $scope.count = response.data.count;
    console.log($scope.count);
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.count; i++) {
      if (response.data.country_name == city[2]) {
        count = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(count);
    console.log(response.data.locations[count].id);
    id = response.data.locations[count];
    $scope.id = id.id;

    $scope.searchid = function() {
      console.log("hahahahaha");
      $http.get("http://api.wego.com/hotels/api/search/new?location_id=" + $scope.id + "&check_in=" + $scope.checkin + "&check_out=" + $scope.checkout + "&user_ip=direct&ts_code=" + $scope.ts_code + "&key=" + $scope.key)
        .then(onSuccessSearch, onErrorSearch);
    };
    var onSuccessSearch = function(response) {
      console.log("2");
      console.log(response.data);
      $scope.search_id = response.data;
    };
    var onErrorSearch = function(response) {
      console.log("here!!!");
      $log.info(response);
      $scope.info = "Could not retrieve data";
    };
  };
  //Error method

  var onErrorName = function(response) {
    $log.info(response);
    $scope.info = "Could not retrieve data";
  };

  /*function hotels(search_id){
    $scope.hotelList = function () {
          $http.get("http://api.wego.com/hotels/api/search/"+search_id+"&ts_code="
              +$scope.ts_code+"&key="+$scope.key)
        .then(onSuccessList, onErrorList);
      };
      var onSuccessList = function (response) {
          $scope.hotels = response.data;
          console.log($scope.hotels);
      };
      var onErrorList = function (response) {
          $log.info(response);
          $scope.info = "Could not retrieve data";
      };
  }*/
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't call `$scope.searchid` from anywhere. So you need to call it

```
$scope.searchid = function () {
   console.log("hahahahaha");
   $http.get("http://api.wego.com/hotels/api/search/new?location_id="+$scope.id+"&check_in="
                +$scope.checkin+"&check_out="+$scope.checkout+"&user_ip=direct&ts_code="+$scope.ts_code
                +"&key="+$scope.key)
        .then(onSuccessSearch, onErrorSearch);
};

$scope.searchid(); // add this line in your code

var onSuccessSearch = function (response) {
     console.log("2");
     console.log(response.data);
     $scope.search_id = response.data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that `$scope.searchid` is never called, try calling `$scope.searchid()` to initiate the second `api` call.

Comment: yes you guys were right. but apart from that, I had to move the second method out of the success callback from the first method and only call the second method from inside the callback.. thanks @shaishab and thalaivar